# Windows Service, strange behaviour with appSettings in app.config

Tags: c#, windows, service, config, appsettings

I'm working on a project that has a shared core component which makes use of an `<appSettings />` section in the corresponding configuration file.

This works fine for the asp.net web part, which uses web.config.

However, there is a Windows service which uses this same shared core component, which (for various reasons) accesses configuration data directly from within (i.e. embedded calls to `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]`) which I can't easily refactor.

This wouldn't be a problem but I am finding that the web service doesn't seem to be able to pick up the appSettings values that I have added to its app.config.  When I deploy this to a dev server, of course it becomes ServiceName.exe.config and the configuration file is otherwise operating correctly (it also contains some `<applicationSettings />` typesafe settings which are working as expected.

Since I can't easily change the shared component, I am stuck with somehow having to work with `<appSettings />` in the Service's app.config file.

Things I've checked: structure seems fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="xxxxx.UploadManagerService.UploadManager" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <xxxxx.UploadManagerService.UploadManager>
            <setting name="NumberOfUploaderThreads" serializeAs="String">
                <value>2</value>
            </setting>
             :
        </xxxxx.UploadManagerService.UploadManager>
    </applicationSettings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="keyname" value="value" />
     :
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

(where : means 'more of the same' :-)

Service runs okay except for where a method in the core component attempts to access any of the `<appSettings />` values.

Is there any way to get this to work properly with a Windows service?  I can't see any reason why it shouldn't just work, but it doesn't (throwing an exception when it tries to access any of the values).

Here's a frag of the kind of place where it falls over:

```
return SendEmailViaAmazonSES(
          new List<string> { clientEmailAddress },
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SalesEmail"],
            "Order Confirmation.",
            content);
```

...which is fortunately trapped in a try:catch and therefore nothing is falling over but those `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]` calls are used throughout and I can't change them without major impact to other systems which already use this core component.

Any ideas?

Other things I've checked: service config file IS in same folder as service exe, dev config DOES contain the right values.

**EDIT 25/5**

Because the service only calls a few methods which require access to the `<appSettings />` values, I've simply cheated by copying those methods into the service itself and using values in `<applicationSettings />` instead.  It's not ideal and I'm still very keen to find out why this doesn't work for a Windows Service, but I couldn't afford to wait so I've taken the pragmatic decision to 'fudge it' in the meantime.  I can always return to this at some later point, or (as happens) forget all about it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

#### File permissions

See if the user under which your Windows service runs has read access to its .config file.

#### Sysinternals Process Monitor

Use [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and filter by your service name to see if the process really tries to access your file via the path you expect it to.

Comment: Seems okay - after all, I can access the <applicationSettings /> values.  I've checked to ensure that there is only one config file as well.  Most odd.

Comment: Are you sure, that the Exception (caught inside the non-modifiable component) is about `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` and not the other parameters?